# Twilio Authy API Support Ending November 2022?

Tags: twilio, authy

we have an application that uses Authy API to send and verify OTP codes via SMS. I recently noticed on Twilio site that Authy API will be deprecated by November 1 2022. Any calls made to API after May 2023 will result in error. https://www.twilio.com/blog/migrate-authy-to-verify

I am unable to understand that should we plan the migration from Authy to Verify before November 1 2022 or May 2023.

Any clarity on this would be helpfull.

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this? What **exactly** are you unable to understand?

Comment: Will the Authy API stop working after November 1, 2022 or it will continue till May 2023.

Comment: "Twilio will support the Authy API through November 1, 2022. After this date, we’ll start to deprecate the service for SMS/Voice. Any requests sent to the API after May 1, 2023, will automatically receive an error" - anything unclear about that? Also, please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Don't use the comment section for important details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/migrate-authy-to-verify):

> Twilio will support the Authy API through November 1, 2022. After this date, we’ll start to deprecate the service for SMS/Voice. Any requests sent to the API after May 1, 2023, will automatically receive an error.

You should plan to migrate sooner rather than later because you do not want to push the migration back until it is a rush to do before the May 2023 cut-off.

The API will continue to work until May 2023, but after that it will no longer work.